# Process Instance is not completed(closed) when using multiinstance subprocess in jbpm

Tags: jbpm

I am using business central for jbpm workflow creation and deployments. I created a process named *multiinstanceprocess*. It's flow is shown here.

**MultiinstanceProcess:**

[image: MultiinstanceProcess]

Which simply calls a subprocess named *simpleinstanceprocess* That has two human tasks as shown here.

**SimpleInstanceProcess:**

[image: SimpleInstanceProcess].

When I run this, it creates instance of *multiprocessintace* and *simpleinstanceprocess:*.

It also creates 2 tasks of *simpleinstanceprocess*. When I complete these 2 tasks, ideally it should close the instance of this 2 tasks but actually it is not closing the process instance, it is still shown as an active instance.

**ActiveProcessInstance:**

[image: ActiveProcessInstance].

Can anyone please help here why process instance is not getting closed?

Comment: you can open the detail of your process instance to see in which node or step it is stuck

Comment: Yes I checked,it stuck at subprocess node.I am using case process for every subprocess, so when using case as a subprocess the flow does not coming back to parent process. I don't know why. But when i tried taking simple bpmn as subprocess,flow is coming back to parent process.Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem it's like if you enter into a do..while loop without giving any condition to go out from this loop. The Sub-process task that you created is a kind of an infinite loop.

in your case you need to execute the sub-process only once, so you only have to uncheck "Multiple instance"

[image]